# JQuery fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I've have a page with several (about `30`) same-sized `divs`. But the `class` is different for them such as:

```
.mosaic-block, .events, .exhibitions, .gallery, .sponsors, .hospitality, .workshops, .lectures {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:6.36896%;
    height:22.2287%;
    margin:2px;
}
```

Next, I've a `navi` class such as:

```
<div id="navi">
    <a href="#"><div id="t0" class="n0 lfloat"><img src="images/home.png"><span>Home</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t1" class="n1 lfloat"><img src="images/events.png"><span>Events</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t2" class="n2 lfloat"><img src="images/workshops.png"><span>Workshops</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t3" class="n3 lfloat"><img src="images/lectures.png"><span>Lectures</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t4" class="n4 lfloat"><img src="images/exhibitions.png"><span>Exhibitions</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t5" class="n5 lfloat"><img src="images/hospitality.png"><span>Hospitality</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t6" class="n6 lfloat"><img src="images/gallery.png"><span>Gallery</span></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="t7" class="n7 lfloat"><img src="images/sponsors.png"><span>Sponsors</span></div></a>
</div>
```

My aim is that if a user clicks on `Events`[ie, `div #t1`], all boxes will fade out except those having the class `.events`. Similarily, for the other options as well. I'm using `Jquery` for this. But my code is too long.Is there any way of shortening it?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('a #t0').click(function() {
        $("*").animate({ 
            opacity: 1.0
            }, 500 );

        });

    $('a #t1').click(function() {
        $("#t1").toggleClass("active");
        $(".exhibitions, .workshops, .sponsors, .hospitality, .lectures, .gallery").animate({ 
            opacity: 0.0
            }, 500 );
        $(".events").animate({ 
            opacity: 1.0
            }, 500 );

        });
</script>
```

Similarily, for `#t2`, `#t3`, `#t4`, etc.
Is there any way of shortening the code?

**EDIT#1**

I mean do I have to write `.click(function()` `7` times for each `#t` individually and exclude that class when writing `$(".exhibitions, .workshops, .sponsors, .hospitality, .lectures, .gallery").animate()`??

Also, how to remove `.active` class when the user clicks on some other option?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery `fadeOut()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try: [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ahelah/6#)

You have to specify a common class for all the boxes, I have used `boxes`.

It also handles "Home", which will show all the divs. Sets the clicked `div` class to `active`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('a #t0').click(function() {
            $(".boxes").animate({ 
                opacity: 1.0
                }, 500 );

        });


        $("#navi a").click(function() {
            c = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

            if(c != "home") {
                $('.' + c).animate({ 
                   opacity: 1.0
                 }, 500 );
                $('.boxes').not('.' + c).animate({ 
                   opacity: 0.0
                 }, 500 );

                $(".active").removeClass('active');
                d = $(this).find('div')[0];
                $(d).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd already started with this one only. The thing is it is first executing `fadeIn` and **then** `fadeOut` which creates a time lapse.
My code was doing things simultaneously.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22227/discussion-between-xan-and-atoztoa)

Comment: It works fine now, still clicking `Home` **fades in** all as expected but then **fades out** all.

Comment: I removed `#t0` from `navi a` parent-->works fine now.

Also, how to assign an `active` class to the selected `navi a` element that is removed when another `navi a` element is clicked.

Comment: @xan: My answer already shows the adding and removal of classes. Take a look.

Comment: For the Home issue, just do a check like `c != "home"`

Comment: I wanted to apply `.active` to `<div id="t1" class="n1 lfloat">` such that it becomes `<div id="t1" class="active n1 lfloat">`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would create some better identifiers on your main menu, so that it's easier to identify which section you want to load:

```
<a href="#" id="home">....</a>
<a href="#" id="events">....</a>
<!-- etc -->
```

I can't actually tell from your question what the content divisions look like. So let's assume they look like this (I will use the `content` class to fade out non-selected content):

```
<div class="home content">...</div>
<div class="events content">...</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

To shorten your JS you can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` for the fades, `addClass()` and `removeClass()` for class management, and you only need one `click` event listener as you can assign it to all the links.

```
$('#navi a').click(function() {

    // only run if clicked anchor is not active
    if (! $(this).hasClass('active')) 
    {
        // active class management
        $('#navi a').removeClass('active'); // remove class from all anchors
        $(this).addClass('active');         // add class to selected anchor

        // fade out / fade in required content
        var showContentByClass = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
        $('.content').not(showContentByClass).fadeOut('slow');
        $(showContentByClass).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

In the example above I've also added a check which makes sure the selected option is not the currently shown content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` functions, and to find the elements that do not have the `events` class, use a CSS not selector `not(.events)`